# How do I automatically run an NPM script after webpack dev server has been started?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, electron

I'm doing a Vue project that runs on Electron. Since Vue uses webpack dev server to run the Vue app in development mode, I need to launch Electron with the dev server URL right after compilation completes and dev server has been started. Right after this.

[image]

I know I can manually run Electron after this but I need this task to be automated. My only purpose for this is to get Vue devtools running on Electron. Vue devtools won't work even if I set **`writeToDisk: true`** and open up the **`index.html`** on Electron. It only seems to work over the dev server ([Issue seems to be **`file://`** protocol](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24011)). I found out that It's possible to [open a browser](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropen) after the server has started. But can't run any custom scripts.

So what I want is to automatically run **`cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js`** after I run **`serve`** Vue task and  the dev server has been started. (I also know that this feature is already implemented in [vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) but I'm avoiding all these plugins for multiple reasons)

Comment: Try running `npm run serve && cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js`, if it works, you can add it to your package.json file in the scripts key like:

"scripts" : { "serve-and-electron": "vue-cli-service serve && cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js" }

In your terminal just run `npm run serve-and-electron`

Note: if your serve command doesn't contains the value "vue-cli-service serve", replace it with the same value that you have in the serve key.

Comment: @AndresForonda Thanks for the suggestion but it won't work since `serve` task doesn't end till the server is stopped.

Comment: Hey, use just one & instead, try it, or something like `npm run serve & cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js`, I tried using vite with `npm run dev & npm run build` and it works.

Comment: That will run concurrently which will end up in Electron failing to load the URL most of the time. 

Comment: Try `npm run serve & sleep 10 && cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js`. This will wait 10 seconds before launching Electron, which should give the dev server enough time to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it and managed to create a build tool called [Vuelectro](https://github.com/m4heshd/vuelectro/).

I had to do it programmatically using the `@vue/cli-service` module and manually start the serve process where I could run electron once the webpack dev server was started.

```
const vueService = require('@vue/cli-service');
const service = new vueService(process.cwd());

function serveDev() {
    service.init("development");
    service.run('serve').then(({server, url}) => {
        let electron = spawn(path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules', '.bin', process.platform === 'win32' ? 'electron.cmd' : 'electron'), ['app/electron-main.js'], {stdio: 'inherit'});

        electron.on('exit', function (code) {
            process.exit(0);
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.stack);
    });
}
```

Complete source code can be found [here](https://github.com/m4heshd/vuelectro/blob/master/vuelectro.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend `pre` and `post` to npm scripts, and npm will figure out what you want. Because `serve` probably runs in the foreground, a `postserve` would normally not work, but you can get around that by using `&`. This won't wait for any build steps to complete, but if it's a requirement to have it wait, you could throw a short `sleep` in as well.

```
"serve": "my serve command &",
"postserve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js"

// or with a sleep
"postserve": "sleep 5 && cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron dist/main.js"
```

Comment: That's the exact issue why I can't do post scripts. I guess a sleep would be a workaround but still far from a solution. Thank you for suggesting that. I can't believe webpack doesn't have such a simple feature.